# How do you reference the top node using SetNodeStyle in R data.tree?

Tags: r, tree, visualization

I created a tree using the R package data.tree.  I would like to edit the top node only but I am not sure how to refer to it using SetNodeStyle.  Here is the code:

```
library(data.tree)

truven <- Node$new("truven")
  opioid <- truven$AddChild("opioid")
  iro.only <- opioid$AddChild("iro.only")
  ero.n.iro <- opioid$AddChild("ero.n.iro")
     ge.27mth <- ero.n.iro$AddChild("ge.27mth")
     l.27mth <- ero.n.iro$AddChild("l.27mth")
  ero.only <- opioid$AddChild("ero.only")

SetGraphStyle(truven, rankdir = "TB")
SetEdgeStyle(truven, arrowhead = "vee", color = "grey35", penwidth = 1)
SetNodeStyle(truven, style = "filled,rounded", shape = "box", fillcolor = "Yellow", 
                  fontname = "helvetica", tooltip = GetDefaultTooltip)     

 SetNodeStyle(truven$truven, style = "filled,rounded", shape = "box", fillcolor = "Green", 
         fontname = "helvetica", tooltip = GetDefaultTooltip)     


 plot(truven)
```

Notice I tried to reference the top node with truven$truven.  It did not work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No I did not.  I have since move on from R.  Not using it anymore.  I would not recommend it if you ask me.

Comment: I'll submit an issue to the [data.tree GitHub page](https://github.com/gluc/data.tree).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SetNodeStyle(truven$truven, style = "filled,rounded", shape = "box", fillcolor = "Green", inherit = FALSE, fontname = "helvetica", tooltip = GetDefaultTooltip)
```

It should work fine, I think you missed `inherit = FALSE` in the `SetNodeStyle` function.